failed_generation with Groq LLM and llama index in Python
My code is the following:
from llama_parse import LlamaParse
from llama_index.llms.groq import Groq
from llama_parse.base import ResultType, Language
from llama_index.core.node_parser import MarkdownElementNodeParser

parser = LlamaParse(
    api_key="xxx",
    result_type=ResultType.MD, 
    language=Language.ENGLISH, 
    parsing_instructions="""\
        The document is an exam documents. \
        It contains many tables and images. \
        Do not parse neither the definition, nor requirements, nor explanation sections.\
    """,
)

llm = Groq(
    model="llama3-8b-8192", 
    api_key="xxx",
)

documents = parser.load_data("path/to/file.pdf")

node_parser = MarkdownElementNodeParser(llm=llm, 
     summary_query_str="""
     The document is a property valuation documents. \
     It shows the key metrics for a property sale. \
     The paper includes detailed figures like the price, the size of the property, \
     the year of construction, the number of bedrooms and bathrooms. \
     Answer questions using the information in this document and be precise. \
     Skip lines for each bullet point. \
     Answer with only one number if asked for it.""")

nodes = node_parser.get_nodes_from_documents(documents)

But it raises an error:

BadRequestError: Error code: 400 - {'error': {'message': "Failed to
call a function. Please adjust your prompt. See 'failed_generation'
for more details.", 'type': 'invalid_request_error', 'code':
'tool_use_failed', 'failed_generation': '\n{\n
"tool_calls": [\n    {\n      "id": "pending",\n      "type":
"function",\n      "function": {\n        "name": "TableOutput"\n
},\n      "parameters": {\n        "table_id": "29 Jones St",\n
"table_title": "Property Information",\n        "summary": "Summary of
property information"\n      }\n    }\n  ]\n}\n'}}

Any idea why I get that please? I have tried many things and none seems to work.

Hi, the error is saying that you have problems in the prompt. Which prompt are you using? The prompt is not present in the code snippet.

Hi, I've updated the prompt for the parsing, otherwise, I have no other prompt. Am I missing something ?

You may like to take a look at this:
https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/discussions/24309
